# Ruby Open3.popen3 Does Not Return STDOUT on Windows 7 (capybara-webkit)

Tags: ruby, windows-7, capybara, capybara-webkit

Whenever I attempt to run tests against capybara-webkit, it is not able to find the listening port, so it attempts to use 0, which results in the following error:

```
Failure/Error: visit user_path
Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL:
  The requested address is not valid in its context. - connect(2)
```

After a significant amount of time spent debugging the functionality of capybara-webkit, I found that the problem is the following line of code (capybara-webkit-1.1.1/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb::open_pipe):

```
_, @pipe_stdout, @pipe_stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3(SERVER_PATH)
```

When that invokes the WebKit server, the WebKit server launches and should output something similar to the following to STDOUT:

```
Capybara-webkit server started, listening on port: 53467
```

When I launch the process manually in a console, that is certainly what I see. However, whenever I try to read `@pipe_stdout` or `@pipe_stderr` all I get is `nil`. Even if I wait until the pipe is ready (as seen in the capybara-webkit connection class) for reading using:

```
IO.select([@pipe_stdout], nil, nil, WEBKIT_SERVER_START_TIMEOUT)
```

I still see the same problem. I'm pretty much a novice when it comes to Ruby IO classes, etc. I've tried everything that I can think of to test/debug this and get `Open3.popen3` to correctly return the same message to STDOUT that I can see in the console to no avail.

Any thoughts or ideas on something else to try? Is there something obvious that I'm missing? I know that most of the Capybara maintainers work on Mac and this all seems to work for them, so maybe this is an issue with how `popen3` is working with Windows?

Comment: For reference, I created a similar issue in the capybara-webkit project: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/605

Comment: Unfortunately no. It appears that there aren't any maintainers that run Windows so there isn't much help to be found. The only other thing I could think to try would be to post a similar question in a Windows/Microsoft oriented forum and see if they could offer generic advice about why piping popen may not work in Windows.

Comment: I am abandoning hope on webkit.. I guess I will use poltergeist for my usecase and see where it takes me!

Comment: BTW.. which version of ruby are we using?

Comment: I'm using Ruby 1.9.3p327